# Neumann's problem implies that the mean value of the normal derivative at the boundary is zero.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, laplacian

Show that a necessary condition for the existence of a solution to the Neumann problem
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}+ \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2} = 0 ,\hspace{0.4cm} 0<r<a, \hspace{0.2cm} -\pi < \theta \leq \pi\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(a , \theta) = f(\theta) ,\hspace{0.4cm} -\pi < \theta \leq \pi
\end{cases}
is that $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(\phi)d \phi} =0$$ that is, the mean value of the normal derivative at the boundary is zero.

**My attempt:**

I'm trying to test for this problem. If I'm not wrong, then the general solution to this problem is $$u(r,\theta) = \frac{A_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{r^{n}\left(A_{n}\cos(n\theta) + B_{n}\sin(n\theta) \right)} \hspace{0.8cm} (*) $$ Then, assuming uniform convergence, I get that $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(r ,\theta) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{nr^{n-1}\left(A_{n}\cos(n\theta) + B_{n}\sin(n\theta) \right)}$$ The solution $(*)$ satisfies the problem condition if $$f(\theta) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(a ,\theta) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{na^{n-1}\left(A_{n}\cos(n\theta) + B_{n}\sin(n\theta) \right)}$$ Therefore integrating both sides and assuming that I can interchange the series with the integration, we have that
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\phi)d\phi &= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{na^{n-1}\left(A_{n}\cos(n\theta) + B_{n}\sin(n\theta) \right)}d\phi \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na^{n-1}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\left(A_{n}\cos(n\theta) + B_{n}\sin(n\theta) \right)}d\phi\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na^{n-1}{\left(A_{n}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(n\theta)d\phi + B_{n}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(n\theta) d\phi \right)}\\
&=0
\end{align}
I can notice that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{na^{n-1}} = \frac{1}{(a-1)^2} \hspace{0.3cm}$ if $|a|<1$

I'm not very satisfied with this reasoning and I feel that I have made a serious mistake. So I decided to post this statement and get to know your most expert answers. I appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ An alternative way to show this is to write the Laplace equation as $\Delta u=\nabla\cdot\nabla u=0$ and apply the divergence theorem.

EDIT: Define $D=\{(r,\theta)\,|\,0<r<a,\,-\pi<\theta<\pi\}$ and integrate the Laplace equation over $D$. This gives
$$0=\iint_D \Delta u\,dA=\iint_D\nabla\cdot\nabla u\,dA=\int_{\partial D}\nabla u \cdot\mathbf{\hat{r}}\,ds$$
where the last equality holds by the divergence theorem in two dimensions. $dA$ is the area element, $ds$ is the line element along the boundary, and $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ is the unit normal of the circle. But $\nabla u \cdot\mathbf{\hat{r}}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}$ is precisely the normal derivative. So by the boundary condition, we have
$$0=\int_{\partial D}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\,ds=\int_{\partial D}f(\theta)\,ds.$$

Comment: Your observation seems very interesting to me. Can you give me more details on how to use your suggestion and apply the divergence theorem in this problem please?
I'm trying to apply your suggestion but it is still not very clear to me.

Comment: Sure. I've edited the post to add details.